# Class template for beginners

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-2.x

I want to allow anyone that has never coded to make classes depending on my template with little to no knowledge of Python.

These classes need to do 2 things:

- Inherit from other classes similar to them.
- Contain variables, updating values if they have been changed or keeping them if not.

For the sake of simplicity I don't want to have `super()` on these new classes, as I'm trying to not frighten newcomers with things they can't understand yet. Here's how I did it:

```
class Template(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = "hello"
        self.other_value = "bonjour"
        self.constant_value = 42
        current_class = self.__class__
        inits = []
        while (current_class.__name__ != "Template"):
            inits.append(current_class.init)
            current_class = current_class.__bases__[0]
        for i in reversed(inits):
            i(self)

    def init(self):
        pass

    def info(self):
        print self.value
        print self.other_value
        print self.constant_value
        print ""

class Deep(Template):
    def init(self):
        self.value = "howdy"
        self.other_value = "salut"

class Deeep(Deep):
    def init(self):
        self.value = "hi"

class Deeeep(Deeep):
    def init(self):
        self.value = "'sup"

very_deep = Deeeep()
not_so_deep = Deep()
very_deep.info()
not_so_deep.info()
```

This outputs :

> ```
> sup
> salut
> 42
>
> howdy
> salut
> 42
> ```

Which is exactly what I want, but it looks really weird, obfuscated and non-Pythonic. Any ideas for improvements?

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more how a novice is supposed to use the `Template` class? Should they create their own classes which inherit from `Template`, or should they simply make a copy of the code and modify it to their needs? In either case I don't understand how this is going to be easier for them than just learning to actually write their own class which does what they need.

Comment: The output should really be `'sup`, not `sup`. That has mistakenly been changed in rev. 2, but I can't fix it because it's only a single-character edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of managing the class hierarchy yourself, you should rely on Python's standardized way of doing it: the MRO. You can reach every class in the hierarchy using it without falling in the trap of forgetting some when dealing with multiple inheritance (which your code does):

```
class Template(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = "hello"
        self.other_value = "bonjour"
        self.constant_value = 42

        for cls in reversed(self.__class__.mro()):
            if hasattr(cls, 'init'):
                cls.init(self)
```

However, if your plan is to make support for the call of `super()` on `init` without the user explicitly calling it, I would advise to put the initialization stuff in `init` as well:

```
class Template(object):
    def __init__(self):
        for cls in reversed(self.__class__.mro()):
            if hasattr(cls, 'init'):
                cls.init(self)

    def init(self):
        self.value = "hello"
        self.other_value = "bonjour"
        self.constant_value = 42
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
...
while (current_class.__name__ != "Template"):
...
```

is weird. Do this:

```
...
while current_class != Template:
...
```

it does the same, except comparing classes instead of strings.

---

This is strange as well:

```
for i in reversed(inits):
     i(self)
```

i is used for iteration so it becomes obsucre, are you calling an int? This:

```
for init in reversed(inits):
    init(self)
```

is more explanatory.

---

I don't really know about this next part, but you could define a small lambda

```
extract_first = lambda x: x[0]
```

with an explanatory name, leaving that part of the code as this:

```
extract_first = lambda x: x[0]

while current_class != Template:
    inits.append(current_class.init)
    current_class = extract_first(current_class.__bases__)
for init in reversed(inits):
    init(self)
```

It leaves it with more words and text but less programming lingo. Might be good.

---

Now what I would do if this was for someone new to programming is relay on something else then abstraction of the **init** and abstract in something like biology:

```
class Exists(object):
    perceptible = True


class Alive(Exists):
    can_use_sustenance = True


class Vertebrate(Alive):
    can_move = True


class Mammal(Vertebrate):
    heat_generation = True


class Dog(Mammal):
    pass


class Cat(Mammal):
    pass
```

Tested on my significant other :-)